# firefox extension;how to open link in new tab

Tags: javascript

How do I open the result of chrome.tabs.executeScript in new tab?

```
window.addEventListener("click", whatever())
    function whatever() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'window.getSelection().toString();',
        allFrames: true,
    }, function(result) {
     //open link 'https://'+result.toString() in new tab
    });
};
```

Comment: Try this: window.open('https://'+result.toString(), '_blank').focus();

Comment: `whatever()` should be `whatever`

Comment: window.open is null

Comment: okay.Now it's not null.now nothing is happening at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using window.open with _blank parameter:

```
...
}, function(result) {
  var redirectWindow = window.open('https://'+result.toString(), '_blank');
  redirectWindow.location;
 //open link 'https://'+result.toString() in new tab
});
...
```

Comment: Did you change first "whatever()" to "whatever" just like @epascarello suggested?